# How can I create a single page vertical page turn effect

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a calendar like set of 12 images that appear to flip up when clicked. I know about turn.js but I don't know enough javascript to start from scratch. I do have a programming background and am willing to learn but don't know where to start.

http://pageflip-books.com/index.php#ppp/page/1

is something like what I'm looking for but I want to show the top pages not the bottom ones.

Most of the examples I have found are for books/magazines with two pages side by side.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into CSS animations if I were you. An example can be found here: https://codepen.io/ryrocks/pen/zovXWy

HTML

```
<!-- https://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-page-flip-effect -->
<div id="all">
  <div id="page-flip">
    <div id="r1">
      <div id="p1">
        <div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="p2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="r3">
      <div id="p3">
        <div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="s">
      <div id="s3">
        <div id="sp3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="s" id="s4">
      <div id="s2">
        <div id="sp2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a id="coke" href="#" title="Pure CSS Coke Can"></a>
    <a id="meninas" href="#" title="CSS 3D Meninas"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#all {
    width: 680px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#page-flip {
    background-image: url(https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6h4pDpK.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 340px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#r1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 1315px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1030px, -500px) rotate(-32deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
}

#p1 {
    width: 1285px;
    height: 1388px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#p1 > div {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 285px 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(1030px, 500px) rotate(32deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    width: 285px;
    height: 388px;
    background-image: url(https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/87WOlJH.jpg);
}

#p1 > div > div {
    width: 10px;
    height: 388px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
}

#p2 > div {
    width: 285px;
    height: 388px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url(https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/4FpEEbu.jpg);
}

#r3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 1315px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1030px, -500px) rotate(-32deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

#s3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 70px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(215px, -500px) rotate(-32deg) translate(40px, 0);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

#page-flip:hover #s3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 325px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, -500px) rotate(0deg) translate(40px, 0);
}

#sp3 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    -webkit-transition-property: width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#page-flip:hover #sp3 { width: 11px }

.s {
    width: 285px;
    height: 388px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}

#s2 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 45px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(240px, -500px) rotate(-32deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    position: absolute;
}

#sp2 {
    width: 15px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .18)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    overflow: hidden;
}

#s4 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#page-flip:hover #s4 { opacity: 0 }

#page-flip:hover #s2 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 300px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-15px, -500px) rotate(0deg);
}

#p3 {
    width: 1285px;
    height: 1388px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#p3 > div {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(1255px, 500px) rotate(-32deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 285px;
    height: 388px;
    background-image: url(https://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/6S8oF28.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#p3 > div > div {
    width: 9px;
    height: 500px;
    float: right;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,.20)));
}

#page-flip:hover #r1 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 1570px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1285px, -500px) rotate(0deg);
}

#page-flip:hover #p1 > div {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 285px 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(1285px, 500px) rotate(0deg);
}

#page-flip:hover #r3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 1570px 500px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-1285px, -500px) rotate(0deg);
}

#page-flip:hover #p3 > div {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(1000px, 500px) rotate(0deg);
}

a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -20000px 0 0 0;
    padding: 1px;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition-property: margin;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.01s;
}

#coke {
    width: 253px;
    height: 158px;
}

a:hover {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px dotted #92C7C1;
}

#page-flip:hover #coke {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
    margin: 33px 0 0 14px;
}

#meninas {
    width: 253px;
    height: 167px;
}

#page-flip:hover #meninas {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
    margin: 203px 0 0 14px;
}
```

In this example hover triggers the page flip, but you can modify that to be triggered by a Javascript click event and to show the page that you prefer when the event occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've played around with the example on CodePen and concluded that what I want to do is probably beyond my capability. I get the idea but can't quite get my head round what I need to do to flip the whole thing 90 degrees and flip from the bottom instead. And then work out the right numbers for the size of image I have.